# How to highlight more than one element with introjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I have different DOM elements I want highlighted with the JS library intro.js.
The problem seems to be that I can just define one element to be highlighted:

```
introjs.setOptions({
        steps: [
            {
                element: '.element1',
                intro: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            {
                element: '.element2',
                intro: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                position: 'top'
            }
        ]
    });
```

I haven't found any option that lets me choose more than 1 element. Do I have to create more instances of the introjs object to make this possible?

Comment: Oops! Tried introjs and that tag didn't exist.. didn't think of intro.js. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nice. Check my answer. you should pass node not the selector string !

Comment: It is not possibile, even of you create one more instance of introjs, they will not work together

Comment: @Amina, Check my answer below

Comment: You answer not work. @david want to see to highlight two elements ad the same time in  the same step

Comment: @David, can u confirm Amina point is correct !

Answer (score 0):

By default intro.js start the intro, by adding a gray box layer to the `body` of the document.
This is why if you try to load the intro.js library twice, it willnot work. Only one step can be shown at a time.

If you want, you can load each of the introJs to another container. And they can work together:

You can do it, by start introJs, and specify the parent element. For example:

```
introJs($('h1').parent()[0]).setOptions({
  steps:[
    {element:$('h1')[0],intro:'hi',position:'bottom'},
  ]}).start();

a2=introJs($('h2').parent()[0]).setOptions({
  steps:[
  {element:$('h2'),intro:'hi',position:'bottom'},
]}).start()
```

You can synchronize both intro.js instance by using `onchange` event.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the Node (using `document.___` or `$('.class')` ) not only the Selector. check the below snippet.

```
steps: [
              { 
                intro: "Hello world!"
              },
              {
                element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
                intro: "This is a tooltip."
              },
              {
                element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
                intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
                position: 'right'
              },
              {
                element: '#step3',
                intro: 'More features, more fun.',
                position: 'left'
              },
              {
                element: '#step4',
                intro: "Another step.",
                position: 'bottom'
              },
              {
                element: '#step5',
                intro: 'Get it, use it.'
              }
            ]
```

Reference URL:
https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/programmatic/index.html